# How to increase the value by one each time i click switching the activity back and forth in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to increase the value of variable count by one each time i click on the button to switch the activity back and forth. However, each time i clicked, the count value is still the same. Can someone kindly help ?

I am trying to put some life-cycle android code, but it still does not make any difference.

```
package com.darayuth.learning;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.darayuth.learning";
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String value = "value";
    private int count = 0;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(value, count);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt(value);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener((View v)->{
            sendMessage();
        });

    }
    public void sendMessage(){
        count = count + 1;
        Log.i(TAG, "value: " + count);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message );
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />


</LinearLayout>
```

```
activity_main2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

package com.darayuth.learning;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView  = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using SharedPreferences to store and retrieve the value between your activities.

```
private void storeValue(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    // Store an integer using the Shared Preferences editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("myPreferenceValueKey", value); // Store the value with a key to identify it
    editor.apply();
}

private void retrieveValue(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int defaultValue = 0; // This is the value that's returned if the preference doesn't exist

    // Retrieve the stored value using the associated key
    value = prefs.getInt("myPreferenceValueKey", defaultValue);
}
```

In your first Activity, just call `retrieveValue()` in your `onCreate()` then call `storeValue()` after incrementing the value but before starting the next Activity.

You can create the same functions in your second Activity to store and retrieve the value as needed.

You can learn more about SharedPreferences at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a class with a static variable to hold the `count` variable. And add a function `increment()` to increase the `count`.